# How can I hide a check box inside my web grid with an if function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing this project in Visual Studio 2013, it is an MVC aplication.
So I have this webgrid here:

```
@gridSensorChoose.GetHtml(
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:

    gridSensorChoose.Columns(

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorID", format: @<text>  <span id="SensorID">@item.SensorID</span>  </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("DeviceID", format: @<text>  <span id="DeviceID">@item.DeviceID</span>  </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorType", format: @<text>  <span id="SensorType">@item.SensorType</span>  </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SensorName", @Html.Localize("sensorName").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span><label id="SensorName">@item.SensorName</label> </span>  </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("VAL", format: @<text><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"/></text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("MIN", format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"/> </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("AVG", format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg" /> </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("MAX", format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max" /> </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("SUM", format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" /> </text>),

    gridSensorChoose.Column("INT", format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" /> </text>)

                                ))
```

Now I want to hide **ONLY** the check boxes in the last two rows (in my case "SUM" and "INT"), but also leave the rows and culmns displayed (regardless if they show nothing), if the value of the third row (in my case @item.SensorType) is less than 100 for example.

What I started doing in java script was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    var SensorType = tr.find("#SensorType").html();
    if (SensorType < 100) {
        $("#Sum").hide();
        $("#Int").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

But then I realized that another action has to be done in order for the tr to work, becasue nothing is selected, and I just want this to work on page load- as soon as the webgrid is displayed. Cna anyone help?

Here is the output:

```
<table class="webgrid2-table">
<thead>
    <tr class="webgrid2-header">
        <th scope="col">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorID&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorID</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=DeviceID&amp;sortdir=ASC">DeviceID</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorType&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorType</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Sensor Name
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            VAL
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            MIN
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            AVG
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            MAX
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            SUM
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            INT
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">10</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">2</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 15cm</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">3</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 30cm</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">4</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">101</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness prvi</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">5</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">201</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Ait temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">6</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">202</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Air humidity </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">7</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">203</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Wind speed </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">8</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">204</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Wind direction </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">9</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">205</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Precipitation </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">10</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">206</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Solar radiation </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">51</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">20</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Battery </label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorID">56</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="DeviceID">1</span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width">  <span id="SensorType">101</span>  </td>
        <td class="col2Width">  <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness drugi</label> </span>  </td>
        <td class="col1Width"><input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val"></td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="sum" id="Sum" style="display: none;"> </td>
        <td class="col1Width"> <input type="checkbox" name="int" id="Int" style="display: none;"> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your comment and posting your actual html structure the solution is totally different. First **ID** should be unique. You can use classes instead. Second you can use jquery [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate the table like this:

```js
$("table tr").not(":first").each(function() {
  //chech if sensorType is less than 100 and hide the checkboxes
  if (~~$(this).find(".SensorType").text() < 100) {
    $(this).find(".sum").hide();
    $(this).find(".int").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="webgrid2-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="webgrid2-header">
      <th scope="col">
        <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorID&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorID</a>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=DeviceID&amp;sortdir=ASC">DeviceID</a>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <a href="/PredefinedViews/CreateSensorList?selDeviceID=1&amp;sort=SensorType&amp;sortdir=ASC">SensorType</a>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        Sensor Name
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        VAL
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        MIN
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        AVG
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        MAX
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        SUM
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        INT
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">10</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Temperature </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">2</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 15cm</label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">3</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Soil Moisture na 30cm</label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">4</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">101</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness prvi</label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">5</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">201</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Ait temperature </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">6</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">202</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Air humidity </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">7</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">203</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Wind speed </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">8</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">204</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Wind direction </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">9</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">205</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Precipitation </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">10</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">206</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Solar radiation </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-row-style">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">51</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">20</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Battery </label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid2-alternating-row">
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorID">56</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span id="DeviceID">1</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width"> <span class="SensorType">101</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2Width"> <span><label id="SensorName">Leaf wetness drugi</label> </span> 
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="val" id="Val">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="min" id="Min">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="avg" id="Avg">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="max" id="Max">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum" class="sum" style=";">
      </td>
      <td class="col1Width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="int" class="int" style=";">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Okay so this is close, but it hides them all, I just need it to hide the ones where the sensorType is less than 100.

Comment: This is simple. Can you post a simple structure of the grid?

Comment: Ok I simplified the grid

Comment: I want the html output :)

Comment: Still a newbie, sorry, I edited my question so you should see my output now

Comment: It worked! Can I use the same example if I want to hide MIN, AVG and MAX if the sensorType is greater than 100?

Comment: Yes(same way) but remember to change id to class. You can't have multiple id's insise the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Could you post a fiddle?
Maybe this could do it:

```
$('tr').not(':first').each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this),
        sensorTypeVal = parseInt($tr.find('td').eq(2).find('span').text());
    if(sensorTypeVal < 100) {
        $tr.find('td').eq(-1).find('input').hide();
        $tr.find('td').eq(-2).find('input').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/za6ze7d7/

So if the number is less than 100, I need to hide sum and int column in that row only

Comment: I understand your example, I'm just having an extremely hard time adjusting it to my project...

Comment: You realise that there are elements with same id so there is no way this one to work? Also _need it to hide the ones where the sensorType is less than 100_ so also no way with this.

Comment: Please check this updated fiddle that uses your new code output: http://jsfiddle.net/za6ze7d7/2/

Comment: Better but OP wants to hide checkboxes not parent td.

Comment: ... well then he should add ".find('input')" or replace "hide()" with "empty()" - should be no big deal, although i think he isnt that petty.